# Where is the binary file, "Eclipse C/C++ Stand-alone Debugger" on fedora 29 Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse-cdt, fedora, binaryfiles

System:  fedora 29 workstation.

I want to learn C language , I installed Eclipse on fedora `$ sudo dnf install eclipse eclipse-cdt` , when I ran the first time Eclipse, it showed those windows.

[image]

And always when I run "Eclipse" it shows those windows first.
What does this mean?, where is the binary file?

Comment: Looks like you're not running Eclipse, you're running the stand-alone debugger.

Comment: Oh, sheet, I think you are right. I have two application's icon of Eclipse in the "Activities overview".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ona fedora 29 workstation, after run the followings commands:

```
$ sudo dnf install eclipse eclipse-cdt
```

You will have 2 application's icon of Eclipse.

[image]

For both  java language and C/C++ language, select the icon that says "Eclipse" .